# How to dynamically change the value of prop in the interface depending on value of other prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to set value of `duration` to `null` for both IToastSmall and IToastLarge, when `actionLabel.length > 0`. How can I achieve that?

```
interface IToastBase {
    id: string;
    open: boolean;
    title?: string;
    content: string;
    actionLabel?:string;

}

interface IToastSmall extends IToastBase{
    smallSize?: true;
    duration: 4000 | 5000 | 6000;
}

interface IToastLarge extends IToastBase{
    smallSize?: false;
    duration: 6000 | 7000 | 8000;
}

type IToast = IToastSmall | IToastLarge
```

Comment: this is just typing, Where is the full code?

Comment: Can the duration value dynamically change at typing level? I thought full code was too large to paste it here so I simplified the problem, which was dynamically changing type.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dynamically"? You can come up with a static type for `IToast` that represents this constraint, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WoYR9N), but there's nothing "dynamic" about it, and it's probably not very useful either because TS doesn't currently discriminate unions by string length.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, you might want to [edit] the question with code that demonstrates the missing use cases.  Let me know how to proceed here.